# Best Statistical Techniques for Order Sensitive Data

Tags: order-statistics, genetic-algorithms, spatio-temporal

### Problem

I am writing a Genetic Algorithm (GA) that aims to find the best order of performing a given set of tasks to fulfill an objective.

Imagine there are a set of tasks `T1, T2, T3 ... TN` where `N` is a finite number e.g 5. All these tasks are operations that when applied one after the other change some input program. The GA essentially allows me to randomly create a set of task sequences (solutions) that best fit a defined problem. The solutions contain tasks with an arrow showing the subsequent task to execute. A solution can also have duplicate tasks, but the total number of tasks must be `N`.

Here are examples of solutions:

```
Sol1 = [T1 -> T3 -> T5 -> T2 -> T4]
Sol2 = [T4 -> T4 -> T4 -> T1 -> T4]
Sol3 = [T3 -> T1 -> T2 -> T3 -> T4]
Sol4 = [T1 -> T4 -> T3 -> T2 -> T5]
.
.
.
```

The performance of each solution can be verified against a fitness function `F` that takes the solution as an argument and returns a float between `0` and `1`. `1` being the best solution, `0` being the worst.

So using the same example:

```
Sol1 = [T1 -> T3 -> T5 -> T2 -> T4] | F(Sol1) = 0.754
Sol2 = [T4 -> T4 -> T4 -> T1 -> T4] | F(Sol2) = 0.521 
Sol3 = [T3 -> T1 -> T2 -> T3 -> T4] | F(Sol3) = 0.112
Sol4 = [T1 -> T4 -> T3 -> T2 -> T5] | F(Sol4) = 0.964
.
.
.
```

### **Question:**

Given the information above, I need an adequate (appropriate) statistical technique that can allow me to analyze how the  **arrangement (ordering) of tasks** affects the final fitness value.

I want to be able to make statistically justifiable claims such as "When applying T4 after T3 we typically see a loss in fitness" or "In order to maximize fitness, T1 should never be the final task ..."

It would also be quite helpful if there are other interesting statistical attributes I can analyze given the sample data I have provided.

Comment: To decide if the location of $T_1$ is important, you could do linear regression where the independent variable is position of $T_1$ in the permutation (as a categorical variable) and dependent variable is the score.